# Query string, Uploading an image and storing it as JSON data

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

There is a basic form on the client side, the user can upload an image from their computer and I'd like to take the query string of there image and store it into JSON data so I can store it in mongoDB atlas. Am I going about this the correct way?

This is the route in express

```
app.get('/home',(req, res)=>{
    res.render('home');
});
```

HTML form client

```
<form action="">
            <input type="file" name="pic" accept="image/*">
            <input type="submit">
        </form>
```

I guess I'm just a little confused about the middle piece that connects these two. I know that I can access the data from the query string by using  req.query.pic but is that string sufficient enough to actually store the image? Wouldnt that just be the name of the image?

Comment: You need to use a middleware like `multer` to handle file data. Please take a look at https://github.com/sridharrajs/nodejs-express-multer-pug-file-upload to connect pic and form data

Comment: I guess the name middleware would be appropriate and makes sense now, thank you.